# Simple Junit class is not calling the @Before method

Tags: java, junit

I'm learning TDD in Java. I made a simple following test class:-

```
   public class EnrollingServiceTest extends TestCase {
        private EnrollingService enrollingService;

        public EnrollingServiceTest( String testName )
        {
            super( testName );
        }

        @Before
        public void init() {
            enrollingService = new EnrollingService();
        }

        @Test
        public void testEnroll() {
            boolean result = enrollingService.enroll(1l, 1l);
            assertTrue(result);
        }
    }
```

I put a break point to debug test execution. I found init() is never called. First called the constructor and then call goes to testEnroll(). Why @Before isn't called by the Junit framwork?

Comment: `extends TestCase`?? (Maybe you run the test as Junit3 so no annotations)

Comment: Assuming you're using JUnit 4.x, you shouldn't (need to) do `extends TestCase`.